# What is the best way to run an app in the background

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm making a simple app testing Lottie animation library in swift. The code is perfectly running when i lunch the app for the first time. But if i relaunch it from the background, the animation stops.

How do i keep the animation running in the background so when i switch to another app and back again, i see the animation working.

I just started learning swift, so i apologize in advance.

```
import UIKit
import Lottie

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var animationView: AnimationView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SetupAnimation()
    }

func SetupAnimation() {
        let animationView = AnimationView(name: "kiss")
        animationView.frame = self.animationView.frame
        self.animationView.addSubview(animationView)
        animationView.loopMode = .autoReverse
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.play()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are one simple thing which will help you to play your animation.

Add following notification of `willEnterForegroundNotification` in your view controller where you have added animation.

Another thing, Declare Lottie's AnimationView's instance globally. See following code

```
class MyClassVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var animationView : UIView!
    var animation : AnimationView?

    func setupAnimation() {
        animation = AnimationView(name: "kiss")
        animation?.frame = self.animationView.bounds
        self.animationView.addSubview(animation!)
        animation?.loopMode = .autoReverse
        animation?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animation?.play()
    }

    @objc func applicationEnterInForground() {
        if animation != nil {
            if !(self.animation?.isAnimationPlaying)! {
                self.animation?.play()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupAnimation()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationEnterInForground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

This will play animation when application come in foreground from background.

Comment: Bro, I love you! hahaha .. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MustafaAljaburi, Pleasure to help you bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
    animation.play()
}
```

Another thing is wring here

```
var animation: AnimationView!

func SetupAnimation() {
        animation = AnimationView(name: "kiss")
        animation.frame = self.animationView.frame
        self.animationView.addSubview(animation)
        animation.loopMode = .autoReverse
        animation.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   }
```

I don't see any purpose of `animationView` to be kind of `AnimationView`. You can change it to `UIView`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var animationView: AnimationView!
```

to

```
@IBOutlet weak var animationView: UIView!
```

Comment: it did not work :( . And i tried before the UIView, but it seems this is how Lottie library works. I have to name the class AnimationView.

Comment: @Ratul, `AnimationView` is custom class of `Lottie` library where animation perform.